# What is the correct root node for 'sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master' index?

Tags: solr, indexing

I am working on a task to move a Sitecore installation search from Lucene to Solr on Sitecore version 8.2. I am using Solr version 5.1 as it is the recommended version for sitecore 8.2. All the other indexes build correctly but I am having an issue while building `sitecore_marketingdefinitions_master` index.

The error says:

> Root item could not be found

Upon investigating the config file for that index, I saw that the root node points to `<Root>{09CF9489-8F71-4A16-B707-4F013D8CDEFB}</Root>`. This item was not found in my local instance.

Since this is the default config for the index, I was wondering if someone could point me to the correct root node that I should use in this case! Or is it ok if I change the root node path to '/sitecore' node?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is `/sitecore/system/Marketing Control Panel/Funnels` in the `master` database.

Comment: Thank you very much! I could not find funnels though. However, I would set it to 'Marketing Control Panel' in that case!

Answer (score 2):

I had this error come up on the `sitecore_marketingdefinitions_web` during an upgrade from 8.2.2 to 9.0.1. What worked for me was doing a Smart Publish on the site, then trying to rebuild of that index. The rebuild was successful after that change.